# Why differential scattering cross sectional area is same for Lab frame and centre of mass frame

Tags: coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Differential scattering cross section is denoted by:

$\frac{{d\sigma}}{{d\Omega}}$

Here, "$d\sigma$" represents the infinitesimal differential scattering cross-sectional area, which is not a physical area but a mathematical concept defined as:

$d\sigma=\dfrac{Number\; of\; particles\; scattered\; per\; unit\; time\; into\; the\; solid\; angle\; d\Omega}{flux\; of\; incident\; particles}$

and "$d\Omega$" represents the solid angle into which particles are scattered during a collision or scattering event.

[image]

In Laboratory frame and Centre of mass frame we write differential scattering cross sections as $\frac{{d\sigma}}{{d\Omega_{lab}}}$
and $\frac{{d\sigma}}{{d\Omega_{cm}}}$

I understand that $d\Omega = sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ must be different for both frames as scattering angles are different in both frames.

My question is that how come $d\sigma$ remains same in both frames.

As $d\sigma$ is about the number of particles scattered into some infinitesimal solid angle so it should be different according to the solid angles ${d\Omega_{lab}}$ or ${d\Omega_{cm}}$, into which particles will scatter in lab or cm frame.

Please help me understand why this quantity $d\sigma$ remains same in both frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that $\langle|\mathcal{M}|^2\rangle_{COM}
=\langle|\mathcal{M}|^2\rangle_{LAB}$
because Mandelstam variables are invariant.
However, the angular dependence of $d\sigma$ does change in the lab frame.

For example, consider Compton scattering.
For Compton scattering in the center of mass frame we have
the following momentum vectors and spinors.
\begin{align*}
p_1&=\underset{\text{inbound $\gamma$}}
{\begin{pmatrix}\omega\\0\\0\\ \omega\end{pmatrix}}
\\[1ex]
p_2&=\underset{\text{inbound $e^-$}}
{\begin{pmatrix}E\\0\\0\\-\omega\end{pmatrix}}
& u_{21}&=\underset{\substack{\text{inbound $e^-$}\\\text{spin up}}}
{\begin{pmatrix}E+m\\0\\-\omega\\0\end{pmatrix}}
& u_{22}&=\underset{\substack{\text{inbound $e^-$}\\\text{spin down}}}
{\begin{pmatrix}0\\E+m\\0\\\omega\end{pmatrix}}
\\[1ex]
p_3&=\underset{\text{outbound $\gamma$}}
{\begin{pmatrix}\omega\\\omega\sin\theta\cos\phi\\\omega\sin\theta\sin\phi\\\omega\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}}
\\[1ex]
p_4&=\underset{\text{outbound $e^-$}}
{\begin{pmatrix}E\\-\omega\sin\theta\cos\phi\\-\omega\sin\theta\sin\phi\\-\omega\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}}
& u_{41}&=\underset{\substack{\text{outbound $e^-$}\\\text{spin up}}}
{\begin{pmatrix}E+m\\0\\p_{4z}\\p_{4x}+ip_{4y}\end{pmatrix}}
& u_{42}&=\underset{\substack{\text{outbound $e^-$}\\\text{spin down}}}
{\begin{pmatrix}0\\E+m\\p_{4x}-ip_{4y}\\-p_{4z}\end{pmatrix}}
\end{align*}

The expected probability density is
\begin{equation*}
\langle|\mathcal{M}|^2\rangle_{COM}
=
\frac{e^4}{4}
\left(
\frac{f_{11}}{(s-m^2)^2}
+\frac{2f_{12}}{(s-m^2)(u-m^2)}
%+\frac{f_{12}^*}{(s-m^2)(u-m^2)}
+\frac{f_{22}}{(u-m^2)^2}
\right)
\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
f_{11}&=-8 s u + 24 s m^2 + 8 u m^2 + 8 m^4
\\
f_{12}&=8 s m^2 + 8 u m^2 + 16 m^4
\\
f_{22}&=-8 s u + 8 s m^2 + 24 u m^2 + 8 m^4
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}
\end{equation*}

Recall the Mandelstam variables are
\begin{align*}
s&=(p_1+p_2)^2
\\
t&=(p_1-p_3)^2
\\
u&=(p_1-p_4)^2
\end{align*}

Compton scattering experiments are typically done in the lab frame where the electron is at rest.
Define Lorentz boost $\Lambda$ for transforming momentum vectors to the lab frame.
\begin{equation*}
\Lambda=
\begin{pmatrix}
E/m & 0 & 0 & \omega/m\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\omega/m & 0 & 0 & E/m
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The electron is at rest in the lab frame.
\begin{equation*}
\Lambda p_2=\begin{pmatrix}m \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Mandelstam variables are invariant under a boost.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
s&=(p_1+p_2)^2=(\Lambda p_1+\Lambda p_2)^2
\\
t&=(p_1-p_3)^2=(\Lambda p_1-\Lambda p_3)^2
\\
u&=(p_1-p_4)^2=(\Lambda p_1-\Lambda p_4)^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

In the lab frame, let $\omega_L$ be the angular frequency of the incident photon
and let $\omega_L'$ be the angular frequency of the scattered photon.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\omega_L&=\Lambda p_1\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{\omega^2}{m}+\frac{\omega E}{m}
\\[1ex]
\omega_L'&=\Lambda p_3\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{\omega^2\cos\theta}{m}+\frac{\omega E}{m}
\end{aligned}
\tag{3}
\end{equation*}

It can be shown that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
s&=m^2+2m\omega_L
\\
t&=2m(\omega_L' - \omega_L)
\\
u&=m^2-2 m \omega_L'
\end{aligned}
\tag{4}
\end{equation*}

Then by (1), (2), and (4) we have
\begin{equation*}
\langle|\mathcal{M}|^2\rangle_{COM}=
2e^4\left(
\frac{\omega_L}{\omega_L'}+\frac{\omega_L'}{\omega_L}
+\left(\frac{m}{\omega_L}-\frac{m}{\omega_L'}+1\right)^2-1
\right)
\end{equation*}

Hence
\begin{equation*}
\langle|\mathcal{M}|^2\rangle_{COM}
=\langle|\mathcal{M}|^2\rangle_{LAB}
\end{equation*}

Lab scattering angle $\theta_L$ is given by the Compton formula.
\begin{equation*}
\cos\theta_L=\frac{m}{\omega_L}-\frac{m}{\omega_L'}+1
\tag{5}
\end{equation*}

It follows that
\begin{align*}
\langle|\mathcal{M}|^2\rangle_{LAB}
&=2e^4\left(
\frac{\omega_L}{\omega_L'}+\frac{\omega_L'}{\omega_L}+\cos^2\theta_L-1
\right)
\\
&=2e^4\left(
\frac{\omega_L}{\omega_L'}+\frac{\omega_L'}{\omega_L}-\sin^2\theta_L
\right)
\end{align*}

To show that $\theta_L\ne\theta$, substitute (3) into (5) to obtain
\begin{equation*}
\cos\theta_L=\frac{m^2}{\omega^2+\omega E}
-\frac{m^2}{\omega^2\cos\theta+\omega E}+1
\end{equation*}

Hence $\theta_L\ne\theta$.